# Homeomorphism from $\bar{D}(0,1)$ to itself takes $\mathbb{S^1}$ to $\mathbb{S^1}$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I have been trying to proof the following result, but haven't found any progress. Any hint? I'm studying topology from Munkres and Dugundji

Any homeomorphism from the closed disk $\bar{D}(0,1) = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2}: x^2+y^2\leq 1\}$ to itself sends the unit circle $\mathbb{S^1}$ to $\mathbb{S^1} $ and the open disk ${D}(0,1)$ to $D(0,1)$.

Comment: Show that under a homeomorphism, the image of the boundary of a subset, is exactly the boundary of the image of that subset. Then, apply this to the subset $\bar D$ itself.

Comment: Does that work @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг?  Applying the definition of boundary to the entire space $\overline{D}(0,1)$, using its own topology (that sees no points outside of the closed disk), suggests to me that the boundary is empty. $\Bbb{S}^1$ becomes the boundary only when we view the disk as a subset of the plane.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen So this page does not apply? mathonline.wikidot.com/the-boundary-of-a-set-under-homeomorphisms-on-topological-sp . You are right, it may not, because not every such homeomorphism would extend to one from $\mathbb R^2$ to itself, right? For if it did, then we could apply the lemma on the page, to the disk as a subset of the plane.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг That result certainly applies. But you do see that $A$ is a subset of a topological space $X$ there. What are your $X$ and $A$ here? The definition of the boundary of $A$ uses open sets of $X$ only. Here, of course, we could try to use the open disk in the role of $A$, when $\partial A$ is the circle. But then we would need to show that the homeomorphism maps $A$ to itself, and we are running in circles.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Ok, I see the problem. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

A point $p\in\Bbb S^1$ is characterised by the fact that $\overline{D}(0,1)\setminus\{p\}$ is contractible, whereas $\overline{D}(0,1)\setminus\{p\}$ deformation retracts on $\Bbb S^1$ when $p$ lies in the interior ${D}(0,1)$.

Comment: Thanks Arnaud, Could you be more specific on your hint please? I don't quite see how this can solve the problem.

Comment: @michaelaba a homeomorphism $f: X\to Y $ induces a homeomorphism $ X\setminus\{p\}\to Y\setminus\{f (p)\}$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, it worked out pretty well. Using the fact that  if $p\in \mathbb{S^1}$, then $\bar{D}(0,1)-\{p\}$ is convex, and then is contractible to a point. So it has trivial fundamental group. Wheras, if  $p$ lies in $D(0,1)$, then  there exists a deformation retracts on $\mathbb{S^1}$, whose fundamental group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$. Thanks!

Comment: @michaelaba You're welcome! Glad it worked out.